# Unable to move linear layout inside relative layout in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am unable to drag my linear layout around inside my relative layout. I am using Android Studio 4.1.3. Attached below is an image of the same :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oRT7.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
    
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" />
    
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Kind of hard to tell what's going on here without the layout XML

Comment: Can you show your layout XML code, it might help to understand your issue better.

Comment: just added xml code. Sorry I am new to asking questions regarding my code on the internet

Comment: I see that your code is correct. What actually you want. Please post a picture of your required design.